# need to set permissions for storage/ daily

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I have set recursive permissions for the storage directory but still I need to run the chmod command every day as the log file generated for that day does not get the write permission so 
do I need to do this everyday ?
If yes than I will write a cron

but I feel I am doing something wrong so any assistance will be appreciated as writing a cron for such a task feels grossly wrong.

Please Note :- I am set up on laravel 5.0 on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: no, set CHMOD for directory where logs will be written

Comment: @kallosz okay I will try that but doesn't -R recursive permission cover child directories?

Comment: is permission got revoked everyday from whole recursive log dir?

Comment: Any reason you don't just let your web user own the storage directory?

Comment: @Samuel https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#Recursive_chmod_using_find.2C_pipemill.2C_and_sudo . This link says its -R

Comment: @Devon I am confused whether PHP should own this or the web user ( i am assuming that will be ubuntu )

Comment: It'd be the user that the php processes are running under.  I highly doubt the ubuntu user is running php, apache, or nginx.

Comment: www-data user runs php script on ubuntu, owner should be www-data

Comment: @Devon in my case /etc/php5 is owned by root and I have storage owned by root

Comment: Well, you certainly shouldn't have php running as root.  Just because that configuration directory is owned by root doesn't mean your processes are running as root.  No offense, but It sounds like you should hire a system administrator because this is pretty basic stuff for a sysadmin and not having a sysadmin managing your server likely means you have many unforeseen issues, including security vulnerabilities in your setup.

Comment: @Devon advice taken .. thanks for your time and assistance

Comment: @Devon php by default installs as root as i need to do sudo so if that is incorrect then i could not find any tutorial that does it otherwise

Comment: Any system package has to be installed as root, that doesn't mean it runs as root..

Comment: but then when i do ls -la it shows root root for php and this is for a fresh install

Comment: @DhavalChheda... really can't go into a system administration lesson for you over stackoverflow.  File ownership is not the same as process ownership.  Hire someone to manage this server for you if it's important to you...

Comment: @DhavalChheda Permissions are very different. Root can always write, but not everyone can. And permission can be set to read a file from a folder owned by root, but not change it. Big difference.